# Extracting values from a list of dicts based another value in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a lists of dictionaries:

```py
list = [
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 39},
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 27},
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 18},
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 33},
    ...
]
```

From this, I need to extract the values of `i` and `j` for the entry that has the greatest `diff`.

I've seen a lot of solutions that would simply extract the greatest `diff`, but that's not what's needed here. And I can think of ways to do this that would involve looping through and comparing each value to the others one by one, but that seems neither efficient nor pythonic.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can the `diff`s have same value, thus multiple `dict` with the greatest `diff`?

Comment: @Chris yes, it's possible, but unlikely - in my specific scenario this numbers will be few and in the millions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `max` with `key` argument to specify that you need to find dictionary inside list having maximum value for `'diff'` key:

```
lst = [
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 39},
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 27},
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 18},
    {'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'diff': 33}
]

max_dict = max(lst, key=lambda x: x['diff'])

print(max_dict['i'])  # 1
print(max_dict['j'])  # 1
```